# How to give string into macro?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am writing a code to give the string to the macro..In macro i am writing @"ready to get with:\"%@\".Find out ." How to give the above thing in macro and i need to call that macro and i need to send the string value to that perticular "%@" that is there in the macro..how to give that.....

```
#define MSG_STR(x) 
#define DES_STR [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ready to get:\"%@\".Find out how here.", MSG_STR(x)]
NSString *shareFinalText = MSG_STR(shareWord);
```

I need the final string like """ready to get:shareFinalstring.Find out how here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not totally sure I understand what you want to achieve, but could you not just use the following:

```
#define DES_STR(message) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ready to get:\"%@\".Find out how here.", message];

NSString *shareFinalText = DES_STR(shareWord);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define MSG_STR(x) @"" #x
```

will turn any x into an `NSString` constant e.g.

```
NSLog(@"%@", MSG_STR(a + b));
```

will give output similar to

```
2011-08-25 11:00:10 +0100 otest[89432:707] a + b
```

It works using the fact that the compiler coalesces syntactically adjacent string constants.